# Android Studio 3.0 Emulator crashing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator, ubuntu-16.04

To begin with, the emulator has been giving me trouble since 2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 and it's been associated with a known bug, to which the work around requires you to do the following:

```
$ cd YOURPATH/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64
$ mv libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6  libstdc++
```

This worked at the time. However, in 3.0 when I came across the same issue and used the workaround shown above, I came across another error which crashed the emulator.

```
"Emulator: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)"
```

I have  [a paste](https://pastebin.com/S6488ke5) of the event log in Android Studio as well as a [crash log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wD4qPkd_ovwH8lDHbvwJKHpo7k0Py70B) (the log was too big for Pastebin so I uploaded the text file to Google drive) that I copied from the "Send error report" window. I'm hoping these logs can shed light on the issue at hand here, and I've found nothing online to help with this so far.

My system specs:

- OS : Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)
- cpu: AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor × 8
- gpu: Nvidia GTX 660 (Gallium 0.4 on NVE6)
- RAM: 8GB

List of things I've tried so far(post the initial workaround):

- Increasing/Decreasing AVD memory
- Trying different System images (both x86 and x64)
- Changing the "Emulated Performance: Graphics" settings

"Hardware GLES 2.0"  causes Ubuntu to hang, "Software GLES 2.0" doesn't do anything but open the emulator window without any crash but it doesn't start either.

I'm relatively new to both Android Studio and Ubuntu and not sure how to go about trying to figure out how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you updated everything in the SDK?

Comment: I believe I have, yes. I performed a fresh install of 3.0 as opposed to updating it from 2.2, I checked for updates as well just in case.